# cljs + luminus framework:file upload with google closure

Tags: clojure, clojurescript, google-closure-compiler, luminus

I follow the example code of book [web development with clojure, 2nd edition](https://pragprog.com/book/dswdcloj2/web-development-with-clojure-second-edition) and I have a problem with the file upload with google closure.

I test the file upload with Swagger and it response me **200 ok**, I think the error is from the **upload-file!** function.(see below).

But I look up the [closure api doc](https://google.github.io/closure-library/api/index.html), it seems I use the correct function.

So I was in a trouble, I don't know why it doesn't work...

I need someone help.Here is my code(I use semantic-ui for ui components):

```
(defn upload-file! [upload-form-id status]
 (reset! status nil)
 (let [io (IframeIo.)]
  (gev/listen
   io goog.net.EventType.SUCCESS
   #(reset! status [c/success-message "file uploaded successfully"]))
  (gev/listen
   io goog.net.EventType.ERROR
   #(reset! status [c/warning-message "failed to upload the file"]))
  (.setErrorChecker io #(= "error" (.getResponseText io)))
  (.sendFromForm io (.getElementById js/document upload-form-id) "/upload")))

(defn upload-form []
  (let [status (atom nil)
        form-id "upload-form"]
  (fn []
    [c/modal
     [:div "Upload File"]
     [:div
      (when @status @status)
      [:div.ui.form
       {:id form-id
        :enc-type "multipart/form-data"
        :method "POST"}
       [:label {:for "file"} "select an image for upload"]
       [:input {:id "file"
                :name "file"
                :type "file"}]]]
     [:div
      [:button.ui.primary.button
       {:on-click #(upload-file! form-id status)}
       "upload"]
      [:button.ui.red.button
       {:on-click #(do
                     (.modal (js/$ ".ui.modal") "hide")
                     (reset! status nil))}
       "Cancel"]]
     "upload"])))
```

the components:

```
(defn modal [header content footer id]
 [:div.ui.modal
  {:id id}
  [:div.header header]
  [:div.content content]
  [:div.actions footer]])


(defn success-message [content]
 [:div.ui.green.message
  [:div.header content]])
```

Comment: it's my error....I found it, I should type :form.ui.form, not :div.ui.form.Sorry for this question..

Comment: You can answer your own question and mark this as solved: http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: Thank you  for your reminder @n2o, I will answer it ^_^, at first I think it just a writing error and does not have to answer.But you are right, I should mark it as solved.

Comment: You can even mark your own answer as the correct one ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I solved my question, I should type `[:form:ui.form]` rather than `[:div.ui.form]`.

if you interest in the code, you can view this URL:
[upload image code](https://github.com/G1enY0ung/gallery/blob/develop/src/cljs/gallery/components/upload.cljs)